# What happened to Ashley?

Tags: evil

At the end of S2E2 of *Evil*, Kristen, David, and Ben go to the house of the man who claimed that he was possessed by an angel, searching for his wife, Ashley. When they arrive, he seems to assert that she has been turned into a pile of salt, which the camera then pans to.

Obviously, the most obvious hypothesis is that she was in fact turned into salt, but that seems rather egregiously supernatural for a show where virtually every case has been somewhat open to a mundane (or at most, slightly science-fictional) explanation. However, no alternative hypothesis is proposed by any member of the team. If the implication is that her husband killed her and somehow buried her in the salt, there is no way that she could fit, and there would be blood everywhere. If she simply disappeared and her husband brought a pile of salt into the house or something of the sort, it would seem odd for none of the characters to remark on this possibility or investigate it further.

So what actually happened to Ashley?

Comment: The Kings explicitly said that there will be things that show will not answer. So even though, yes, they set out to let *the viewer decide on what *they believe (can it be explained away or can't it? Is "this" even scientific, psychological, or metaphysical in nature?), I would argue strongly that season two definitely pushed boundaries into the supernatural/metaphysical and the show feels like it has a stronger mythology now. Alexis alone seeing "Goat-man" at the door, despite that *seemingly LaRoux was there I think is big tell for something we can't explain...

Comment: The Black Goo (that keeps popping up from the Sanctuary), Leland now also seeing the Djinn, Sister Andrea seeing that other Demon, Season two featured weird power exchanges (including Eddy Dolls), etc -- There is too much there to ignore or dismiss as perfectly scientifically explainable...